# How to retrieve svg file name or path from itself using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Please is there a possible way I can get the file name of an svg file directly from the file itself for example I have this folder and files

```
+mainFolder/       <!--Main Folder-->
 +svgImgs/         <!--SVG image Folder-->
  +image.svg       <!--SVG image-->
 +index.php        <!--index page of Main Folder-->
```

Then in my index page I have this `ajax()` call that retrieves and appends the `image.svg` file.

```
$.get('svgImgs/image.svg', null, function(data){
    var svgNode = $('svg', data);
    var docNode = document.adoptNode(svgNode[0]);
    $('div').append(docNode);
}, 'xml');
```

Now the issue is that I want to trigger an `onclick` event for the `svg` files as I have multiple of them. and I want to pass the svg file name or svg path as the parameter

```
<svg>
    <script>
        $('svg').on('load', function(){
            fileName = //get the file name or file path
            $(this).attr('onclick', 'myFunction('+fileName+')');
        })
    </script>
</svg>
```

So I can run the `myFunction()` in my index file

```
function myFunction(svg){
    //functions here
}
```

Please any better suggestion on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `$.get()` call in another function and pass the filename as a parameter, which will then allow you to do this for multiple svg files easily...

```
function getSvg(filename) {
    $.get(filename, null, function(data) {
        var svgNode = $('svg', data);

        svgNode.on("click", function() {
            myFunction(filename);
        });

        var docNode = document.adoptNode(svgNode[0]);
        $('div').append(docNode);
    }, 'xml');
}

getSvg("svgImgs/image.svg");
// get other svg files...
```

Answer (score 1):

From what @Archer has written, this is a short and quick method. Instead of nesting your `$.get()` call in a function, you can just do this

```
$.get(filename, null, function(data) {
    var svgNode = $('svg', data);

    svgNode.on("click", function() {
        myFunction(filename);
    });

    var docNode = document.adoptNode(svgNode[0]);
    $('div').append(docNode);
}, 'xml');
```

Then in `myFunction()` you just get the value passed

```
function myFunction(svg){
    console.log(svg);
}
```